# Faker YML add 1 hour to a date

Tags: faker

My question is about Faker.
I need to add one hour to a created date
Like this :

```
MyEntity: 
    startAt: '<dateTimeBetween("- 10 days", "now")>'
    endAt: $startAt + 1 hour
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that does not exist yet. Need to create a custom provider

Like this :

```
public static function manipulateTime($date, $action = '-30 years')
    {
        $date = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $date->modify($action);

        return $date;
    }
```